# Configuring root logger in python

Tags: python, django, logging

I have the following logging configuration in in my Django settings.

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format':
              '%(levelname)s|%(asctime)s|%(name)s>> %(message)s',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
         '': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
         },
        'apps': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    }
}
```

With this configuration I expect my 'apps' to log at DEBUG level and any other modules to log only ERROR and above. But I see DEBUG messages from other modules. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 11):

Are you using an empty string key in `LOGGING['loggers']` to match the root logger? If so, you could try this instead.

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format':
              '%(levelname)s|%(asctime)s|%(name)s>> %(message)s',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'apps': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        }
    },
    'root': {
       'handlers': ['console'],
       'level': 'ERROR'
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it did not work. Still seeing DEBUG messages from other modules.

Comment: @Chamindu did you try changing `''` to `'root'` instead of moving it out of `loggers`? (I'm a bit late to the party, sorry!)

Comment: I did not try it. This was from a long time back I don't even remember where i tried to do this :)

Comment: I set the root and it helped. But actually I cannot explain to myself why does root has to be configured? I mean what's its purpose.

Comment: I had the opposite problem: using 'root' it showed only WARNING and above, while setting it to the empty string showed also DEBUG and INFO messages.

Comment: I tried to use this combination but it is printing logs twice from `apps`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, with root logger configured a level at `INFO` but seeing DEBUG log message.

Turns out I should not set `'propagate': True` for my other logger which is at level `DEBUG`, since that those logs will be passed to the root logger no matter what level root at.

So my guess here to the original question is that there might be some other modules' logger with `propagate` turned on. set `disable_existing_loggers` to `True` maybe solve this.