# Django+Nginx+Gunicorn : [error] 2194#2194: *15 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream

Tags: django, nginx, django-rest-framework, gunicorn

I have an API that i made using Django 2.1, DRF, Gunicorn, Nginx, and Tensorflow. I am running this on a Droplet with Ubuntu 18.04 x64 and 1 GB of memory.

The API is configured so that it only allows `POST` method to invoke the API. When sending a request, the API will expect a zip file and response a string.

When i first use this on my local machine, nothing went wrong. However, when i move it to the cloud and use `nginx` and `gunicorn` to serve the API, i receive the following error from the `nginx`'s `error.log`

```
[error] 1186#1186: *9 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: CLIENT_IP_ADDRESS, server: HOST_IP_ADDRESS, request: "POST /api/beta/some-app/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/user-name/django-api/django.sock:/api/beta/some-app/", host: "HOST_IP_ADDRESS".
```

After exploring many questions regarding this error, i decided to include the following logging in my django app's `settings.py`

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '{levelname} {asctime} {module} {process:d} {thread:d} {message}',
            'style': '{',
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '{levelname} {message}',
            'style': '{',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'fileDebug': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': "/var/log/debug_django.log",
        },
        'fileError': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': "/var/log/debug_django.log",
        },
        'fileCritical': {
            'level': 'CRITICAL',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': "/var/log/debug_django.log",
        },

    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['fileDebug'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['fileError'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['fileCritical'],
            'level': 'CRITICAL',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },

}
```

The filename for the `django` app's error log is in `/var/log/debug_django.log`. The error log for `gunicorn`'s error log is also in the same directory as `/var/log/gunicorn_error.log`.

After i try to sent the same `POST` request, i still received the same error from `nginx`. However, the `debug_django.log` did not output any error (in fact, it did not output any sorts of informations such as `INFO` or `DEBUG`) and the 'gunicorn_error.log' output no error also
when i run `sudo tail -F /var/log/gunicorn_error.log`

**sudo tail -F /var/log/gunicorn_error.log  output**

```
[2018-10-12 17:46:33 +0000] [1282] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2018-10-12 17:46:33 +0000] [1299] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1299
[2018-10-12 17:46:33 +0000] [1300] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1300
[2018-10-12 17:46:33 +0000] [1302] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1302
[2018-10-12 17:47:09 +0000] [1315] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1315
[2018-10-12 17:57:40 +0000] [1406] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1406
```

I'm not really sure. What is going on with the backend (or `upstream` according to `nginx`). A couple of cases from Stackoverflow is that its either a timeout error or the file size is too big. But according to the log, `gunicorn` experienced no such thing. I've tried removing the `http://` from the nginx `site-enabled` (called `django`) file, but that just makes `nginx` outputs an error saying that it needs that prefix.

It's been a week or so and i haven't found any way to overcome this.

Anybody has any idea on this? Thanks in advance.

Here are the files for `gunicorn` and `nginx`

**/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=user-name
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/user-name/django-api
ExecStart=/home/user-name/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile gunicorn_access.log --error-logfile /var/log/gunicorn_error.log --log --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/user-name/django-api/django.sock DjangoAPI.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/django**

```
upstream django {
    server unix:/home/user-name/django-api/django.sock;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name HOST_IP_ADDRESS;
    client_max_body_size 200M;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/user-name/django-api/;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/user-name/django-api/django.sock;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_buffers 8 32k;
        proxy_buffer_size 64k;
        proxy_request_buffering off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_ignore_client_abort on;
    }
}
```

Comment: Might be worth adding a [`root` logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021704/configuring-root-logger-in-python) at `DEBUG` level to act as a catch-all - just in case your current logging isn't catching the error. Also, I notice you're using a `unix:` socket between Nginx and Gunicorn. Have you tried temporarily switching to a TCP socket to see whether you still experience the problem?

Comment: @WillKeeling Hey thank you for the suggestion. just like you said, it seems that I have to add a `root` logger to capture the error. Then, i changed the `unix:` socket to TCP in nginx. Thanks to that my issues were solved and I'll be providing more detail by answering my own question.